# Error occured in nintex workflow

Tags: nintex-workflow

am learning nintex and got a bit stuck.in the nintex workflow i drag and drop the Query BCS action. after that i try to configure, but one error popup display " An unexpected error is occured"
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EMZOb.png)

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]. Use the "edit" link to improve your *question* - do not add more information via comments. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, but nobody will be able to help with such input "I did something and then things break".

Answer (score 0):

This has occasionally happened to me. Solution, close the browser or tab, and re load it. Make sure you save first.